# Exporting queries to another computer?

Tags: memgraphdb

I have desktop version of Memgraph Lab. At the moment I'm copying queries one by one into shared document on network drive so that I can run them on another server.

On that server I have Memgraph Platform. I wonder can I somehow export queries from my computer to server? Can I save query collection and load it onto another Memgraph Lab instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no export method for queries. You will need to copy-paste them. For that exact purpose, I use one repository on GitHub. That way, I can always access the queries I've copied.